# post form on any input change it contains the input type hidden which changes dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<form id="pricecal">
    <input type="text" onchange="calprice()" class="form-control round-corner-fix datepicker" data-provide="datepicker" placeholder="Check in" value="" required />
    <input type="text" onchange="calprice()" class="form-control round-corner-fix datepicker" data-provide="datepicker" value="" placeholder="Check Out" required />
    <input type="hidden" onchange="calprice()" id="noroom" value="" name="room" />
    <input type="hidden" onchange="calprice()" id="noguest" value="" name="guest" />
</form>
```

my code perfectly works on input text but not on input type hidden
i tried following ways i dont want to loop for every input

```
function calprice(){
    alert('Textarea Change');
}

$(document).on('change', 'form#pricecal input', function(){
    alert('Textarea Change'); 
});

$("form#pricecal input").bind("change", function() {
    alert('Textarea Change'); 
});
```

Comment: How do you change the hidden tags?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish

Comment: i was just trying to post form on input change but it was not working for input type hidden

Answer (score 1):

As you have bound event on the elements that can be triggered whenever you update your input's value:

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').trigger('change');
```

Put this line just after that line of code which causes the value change.

Answer (score 0):

type=hidden
These fields should not be rendered and provide a means for servers to store state information with a form. This will be passed back to the server when the form is submitted, using the name/value pair defined by the corresponding attributes. This is a work around for the statelessness of HTTP. Another approach is to use HTTP "Cookies".

[Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293741/original-purpose-of-input-type-hidden)